# Magento 2 Access shipping code from Payment Moule

Tags: magento2

How can we get the shipping method code from the Payment Module to, activate/deactivate payment method based on selected shipping method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get current shipping method in magento 2 you need to create object instance for **Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart**

Use following code to get shipping method of current quote

```
$om =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cartData = $om->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')->getQuote()
           ->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
```